# Restrict non-numerical values from operation

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am making a calculator in windows forms and I want to make a message box pop up when the user tries to add/subtract/divide/multiply with non-numerical values. I have looked at the old forums that give possible fixes but none have seemed to work so far.

here is my code for the multiply button:

```
private void buttonMul_Click(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    Operand1 = Convert.ToDouble(textOperand1.Text);
    Operand2 = Convert.ToDouble(textOperand2.Text);
    result = Operand1 * Operand2;
    textresult.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `Double.TryParse` method

Comment: You can use a try and catch block and create the message pop up box in the catch block. This will display is the try block doesn't work. Or you can use the Double.TryParse() method.

Comment: I would suggest that you prevent the user from entering invalid input in the first place instead of allowing them to enter invalid input and then playing a "gotcha" kind of error message on them.

Comment: Instead of checking on buton click, create a KeyPress event for your TextBoxes that only handle numbers, backspace, decimal and `-` sign.

Comment: I disagree with above comments. Checking for valid input characters does nothing to ensure that the textbox only contains valid data.  You can write a whole lot of code and it will still likely allow the user to enter non-numeric data into the textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of throwing an error to the user when they enter the incorrect type of input, block them from entering anything but numbers to begin with.

**Event**

Use a keypress event on the textboxes like so:

```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // Get reference to calling control
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;

    // Only allow 0-9, ., -
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && 
        !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) &&
        e.KeyChar != '-' &&
        e.KeyChar != '.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    // Avoid double decimals
    if (e.KeyChar == '.' && textBox.Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    // Ensure hyphen is at the beginning
    if (e.KeyChar == '-' && 
        (textBox.Text.Contains('-') || 
        textBox.SelectionStart != 0))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

This will only allow numeric values, decimal, and hyphen to be entered. Additionally this will also block more than 1 decimal `.` in the input and ensure a user can only enter a hyphen `-` at the beginning of the text.

**Register EventHandler**

To register this eventhandler just add this line of code to your constructor for the form.

```
// Be sure to change yourtextcontrol to the appropriate name.
yourtextcontrol.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(textBox_KeyPress);
```

**Verify input**

You should also use `TryParse` in your click event to double check the entries.

```
private void buttonMul_Click(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (double.TryParse(textOperand1.Text, out Operand1) &&
        double.TryParse(textOperand2.Text, out Operand2)) 
    {
        result = Operand1 * Operand2;
        textresult.Text = result.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        // Error here. You can use a messagebox or whatever suits you.
    }
}
```

Comment: Also need to make sure the minus sign is only in there once at the beginning.

Comment: what is key char?

Comment: @Morgan The character associated with the keypress event. Documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar(v=vs.110).aspx). Basically it's what key you pressed.

Comment: oh.. so what is  TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox; ?

Comment: @Morgan that is a way to get a reference to the TextBox control in which this event is occuring.

Comment: You'll need to create an eventhandler for the textboxes. If you are using visual studio this is very easy. Just use the properties window for the control and look for the events tab. Add a keypress event and use the above code.

Comment: but I also have a eventArgs in visual studio and I don't think it works because the EventArgs is empty

Comment: This is the best current answer.  IMHO you should derive your own `TextBox` and create a `NonNumericTextBox`.

Comment: @Morgan I've updated the answer to show how to register the event

Comment: This code will prevent some invalid input, but it is still trivially easy to make a non-number appear in the text box.

Comment: @David You are right. This will not block pasting in text for instance. One of the reasons I've included the validation in the click method as well.

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason they have to be able to enter other things than numbers for some other functions in your calculator. You can use [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx) which will return false if the value can't be parsed and then show the messagebox

```
private void buttonMul_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool operand1Parsed = double.TryParse(textOperand1.Text, out Operand1);
    bool operand2Parsed = double.TryParse(textOperand2.Text, out Operand2);

    //If we could not parse one of them.
    if(!operand1Parsed || !operand2Parsed)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your message");
        return;
    }

    result = Operand1 * Operand2;
    textresult.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TryParse method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.tryparse.aspx .

That will return false if input ins't numeric value.

```
double result;
if (double.TryParse(textOperand1.Text, out result))
{
   // Do stuff
}
```